# How to save map by using map_server package according to the topics?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the multi_map_merge package to merge map from robot 1 and robot 2. But when I used `rosrun map_server map_saver -f ~/map`, the map is only saved the merge map which is from `/map` topic. But I also would like to save map from `/tb3_0/map` and `/tb3_1/map` topics. I would like to ask how to save map according to the map topics? Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401405/how-to-save-map-by-using-map_server-package-according-to-the-topics?/) by [MirulJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/87165/mirulj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this : 
`rosrun map_server map_saver map:=<your_topic_name>`

---

Originally posted by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) with karma: 277 on 2022-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MirulJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/87165/mirulj/) on 2022-05-26**:
Thank you very much for the answer